# generating random numbers in python with percentage function on what selected value in python

Tags: python, random

Lets say I wanted to generate a random number in python using something like `random.randint(1,100)` but how would I go about making Python want to tend toward selecting higher random numbers? So like if i wanted 80% of numbers above 50 to be chosen with 20% of numbers below 50 to be chosen. like a casino slot machine probability. (we all know there not truly random but are set with probability).

I have tried

```
import random

random.randint(1,100)
select % above 50
```

Comment: random.randint(1,100) will *already* produce numbers above 50 about 50% of the time, right? Perhaps you should use a higher percentage to match the "higher random numbers" part of your question?

Comment: So you want it to be "mostly random"? :)  Your example is only generating a single random number, how do you expect to have 50% of 1 be higher than 50?

Comment: @techie007 Having non-uniform distributions doesn't mean the results aren't random.

Comment: @pjs, right, but it does mean it's "less random." Assuming you *know* the non-uniformity of the distribution, if you can guess the random value more accurately than you can without that knowledge, it has less entropy.

Comment: @NickRusso Yes, the uniform distribution has maximum entropy. The Gaussian distribution isn't max entropy, but most people would agree it fully qualifies as random.

Comment: If I chose a person randomly, they would be likely to think a Gaussian distribution is random (or have no clue what I was talking about). But if I chose from a group of people whose mathematical maturities fell on a Gaussian distribution, I'd be very likely to find a person who knew that a Guassian distribution is not fully random. Unfortunately, the distribution of mathematical maturities is probably more random than normal.

Comment: i am sorry i worded the percent wrong. think of like a casino slot machine where they can change the probability of the payout so like a 80 percent chance that a number over 50 will appear and a 20 percent chance a number under 50. something like that

Comment: @NickRusso Quoting [Parzen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Parzen)'s _Modern Probability Theory and Its Applications_, p.2, "A random (or chance) phenomenon is an empirical phenomenon characterized by the property that its observation under a given set of circumstances does not always lead to the same observed outcome (so that there is no deterministic regularity) but rather to different outcomes in such a way that there is statistical regularity." If outcomes can be predicted with certainty, they are non-random, otherwise they are random. It's categorical, not relative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using a weighted list, like this:

```
import random
my_list = ['A'] * 5 + ['B'] * 5 + ['C'] * 90
random.choice(my_list)
```

See [Python Weighted Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992521/python-weighted-random). To make it twice as likely that a number from 51 to 100 will be chosen instead a number from 1 to 50, do this:

```
import random

my_list = []

for i in range(1, 100):
    my_list.append(i)
    if i > 50:
        my_list.append(i)

print my_list
print 'Random (sort of) choice: %s' % random.choice(my_list)
```

Comment: thanks never thought about using a list. for some reason the basic random.randint(1,100) tends to like to give me a lot of doubles and lower numbers. where i want the possibility of a lower number but not that often. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-uniform distribution such as the [triangular distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html), set the mode equal to the range max, and cast to `int` or round it.