# How to Weight Random Numbers in Python

Tags: python, random, weighted

I came across a script that provides me with a random dice roll between 1 and 6.

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print random.randint(min, max)
    print random.randint(min, max)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

So, I decided to take this script and create a script that uses the random dice roll values and use those as scores in a soccer game.

```
while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    team1_score = random.randint(min, max)
    team2_score = random.randint(min, max)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Now, I have around 20 soccer teams that play in the league. I created a spreadsheet and built a schedule for this league. I read in the 2 teams that are playing each game and roll the dice in the script above and that gives me the score for that game (i.e. team1_score = 5, team2_score = 3)

Now, just like in real life, some of those teams are stronger than others, so I want to write a script that weighs teams stronger than others, and thereby giving it a better chance at winning (higher score than the weaker team). So, if I had a list like this:

Team            Weight

team1   60

team2   20

team3    8

team3    8

team5    4

How would I pass that into `random.randint(min,max)` so that it gives the better probability that the stronger team would get the higher score than the weaker team?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't use the suggested page, but while I reviewed it, I found another solution in the answered solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992521/python-weighted-random

Answer (score 2):

You can first find a relation between the weight of your teams, then divide the random range by this relations, for example here the weight of `team1` is 7.5 time greater than `team3` so When you want to choose a score between this two team based on this relation you can choose the score for `team1` between `max - ((max-min)/7.5)` and for `team3` between `max` and `min`.